# Extracting the template file from the content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I need to extract the template file from a number of Content types. Getting the content type and the DocumentTemplateUrl is easy enough but how do I the file to the desk?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the location for the specific document template is: `[siteurl]/_cts/[content type name]/[document name]` You could download it use the url.

If you could use SP Designer,  you would be able to see all the document templates. It is in this folder: All Files->_cts

[image]